# Pandas - Why there are duplicates after join?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, join

I have train with 3756 rows and test with 500 rows, after join I had 798974 rows.

code for join:

```
test.join(train.set_index('link_1')['claps_link_1_mean'], on='link_1', how='left')
```

Use of drop duplicates is works, but required a lot of time and memory.

Comment: hmmm, `test.join(train.drop_duplicates('link_1').set_index('link_1')['claps_link_1_mean'], on='link_1', how='left')` required a lot of time and memory ?

Comment: I mean drop_duplicates after join operation, because join create a df with 798974 rows

Comment: I'm interested why join create a df with duplicates

Comment: Because that's how it's defined. [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) PS [mre] PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is duplicated values of column `link_1` in `test` and `train`, so for each duplicated values get all combinations between:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({"link_1": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                      'claps_link_1_mean': range(8)})
test = pd.DataFrame({"link_1": [0, 1, 1, 1]})

df = test.join(train.set_index('link_1')['claps_link_1_mean'], on='link_1', how='left')
print (df)
   link_1  claps_link_1_mean
0       0                  0
0       0                  1
0       0                  2
0       0                  3
1       1                  4
1       1                  5
1       1                  6
1       1                  7
2       1                  4
2       1                  5
2       1                  6
2       1                  7
3       1                  4
3       1                  5
3       1                  6
3       1                  7
```

If remove duplicates in one of them before `join` all working well:

```
test.join(train.drop_duplicates('link_1').set_index('link_1')['claps_link_1_mean'], on='link_1', how='left')
```